# Operation on same column based on group attribute

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

Here is an example scenario, I am trying to work out in Crystal Reports. Any guidance in accomplishing the same is appreciated.

Source table, aggregated by Month, Category

```
* Month Category Amt 
* 201512 Project 100 
* 201511 Project 150 
* 201512 Funds   500 
* 201511 Funds   400
```

Output table, Project category remains the same and monthly Project Amounts are deducted from the same month for every other category in the report

```
* Month Category Amt 
* 201512 Project 100 
* 201511 Project 150 
* 201512 Funds   400 (500 -100) 
* 201511 Funds   250 (400-150
```

Comment: Wheres the aggregation been done? in the rpt or sql?  If in rpt you could use formula on the Details section (where all individual data is available) and grouping sections to sum what you need

Comment: Aggregation is at the database level. The report is based on a view. I don't have access to detailed level data for this report.